# How to test login and signup functionality with tsung

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreman, tsung, tsung-recorder

I have integrated Tsung tool. I have Rails, Foreman.
Just tell me an example to check login and signup functionality.

like for login where I can put username and password.
like where do I put signup info into xml file.

Comment: can anybody help me here?

Answer (score 1):

When Username and pwd will be Url parameters
This is One of the way to do it.I did it this way.

```
<http url="/web" contents="{"UserName":"UserName",password:"pwd"}" method="POST"/>
```

Let us know if u did it in a different way.